# Scenekit - How to keep a line between two variable point

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I need to draw a line between two variable points and I have to update the line geometry constantly to keep it in correct position, rotation and height.

I tried below code but the line is flickering because of too many update calls:

```
class Line: SCNNode {
    
    var color       : UIColor
    var radius      : CGFloat
    
    init(from start: SCNVector3, to end: SCNVector3, color: UIColor = .yellow, radius: CGFloat = 0.002) {
        
        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius
        
        super.init()
        
        updateGeometry(from: start, to: end)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func updateGeometry(from start: SCNVector3, to end: SCNVector3) {
        
        //Initial geometry once
        if geometry == nil {
            let geometry = SCNCylinder()
            
            let material = SCNMaterial()
            material.diffuse.contents = color
            geometry.materials = [material]
            geometry.radius = radius
            
            self.geometry = geometry
        }
        
        guard let geometry = geometry as? SCNCylinder else { return }
        
        let vector = SCNVector3(start.x - end.x, start.y - end.y, start.z - end.z)
        
        let height = CGFloat(sqrt(vector.x * vector.x + vector.y * vector.y + vector.z * vector.z))
        let position = SCNVector3 (x:(start.x + end.x) / 2, y: (start.y + end.y) / 2, z:(start.z + end.z) / 2)
        
        //Prevent unnecessary geometry update
        guard !SCNVector3EqualToVector3(position, self.position) || geometry.height != height else { return }
        
        geometry.height = height
        
        self.position = position
        look(at: end, up: SCNVector3(0, 1, 0), localFront: worldUp)
    }
}

//Call updateGeometry in update method to make sure it is in correct shape
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        updateFloatingLine()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post [21886224] - Might try the cylinder approach if you don't have too many of them.  I'm not sure it will solve the flicker problem...

My version of it... put it together via many posts.  It's been a long while since I did this, so I can't remember everything, just that I didn't solve it with geometry.  It was for firing lasers (source to target), so I don't know how it will hold up with your needs, but maybe you can try it.  Good luck

```
let x = SCNNode().buildLineInTwoPointsWithRotation(from: SCNVector3(-vX, vY, vZ), to: SCNVector3(vX, vY, vZ), radius: 0.2, color: UIColor.blue)
        gameNodes.addChildNode(x)

func buildLineInTwoPointsWithRotation(from startPoint: SCNVector3, to endPoint: SCNVector3, radius: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> SCNNode
    {
        let w = SCNVector3(x: endPoint.x-startPoint.x,
                           y: endPoint.y-startPoint.y,
                           z: endPoint.z-startPoint.z)
        let l = CGFloat(sqrt(w.x * w.x + w.y * w.y + w.z * w.z))
        
        if l == 0.0 {
            // two points together.
            let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: radius)
            sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = color
            self.geometry = sphere
            self.position = startPoint
            return self
            
        }
        
        let cyl = SCNCylinder(radius: radius, height: l)
        cyl.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = color
        
        self.geometry = cyl
        
        //original vector of cylinder above 0,0,0
        let ov = SCNVector3(0, l/2.0,0)
        //target vector, in new coordination
        let nv = SCNVector3((endPoint.x - startPoint.x)/2.0, (endPoint.y - startPoint.y)/2.0,
                            (endPoint.z-startPoint.z)/2.0)
        
        // axis between two vector
        let av = SCNVector3( (ov.x + nv.x)/2.0, (ov.y+nv.y)/2.0, (ov.z+nv.z)/2.0)
        
        //normalized axis vector
        let av_normalized = normalizeVector(av)
        let q0 = Float(0.0) //cos(angel/2), angle is always 180 or M_PI
        let q1 = Float(av_normalized.x) // x' * sin(angle/2)
        let q2 = Float(av_normalized.y) // y' * sin(angle/2)
        let q3 = Float(av_normalized.z) // z' * sin(angle/2)
        
        let r_m11 = q0 * q0 + q1 * q1 - q2 * q2 - q3 * q3
        let r_m12 = 2 * q1 * q2 + 2 * q0 * q3
        let r_m13 = 2 * q1 * q3 - 2 * q0 * q2
        let r_m21 = 2 * q1 * q2 - 2 * q0 * q3
        let r_m22 = q0 * q0 - q1 * q1 + q2 * q2 - q3 * q3
        let r_m23 = 2 * q2 * q3 + 2 * q0 * q1
        let r_m31 = 2 * q1 * q3 + 2 * q0 * q2
        let r_m32 = 2 * q2 * q3 - 2 * q0 * q1
        let r_m33 = q0 * q0 - q1 * q1 - q2 * q2 + q3 * q3
        
        self.transform.m11 = r_m11
        self.transform.m12 = r_m12
        self.transform.m13 = r_m13
        self.transform.m14 = 0.0
        
        self.transform.m21 = r_m21
        self.transform.m22 = r_m22
        self.transform.m23 = r_m23
        self.transform.m24 = 0.0
        
        self.transform.m31 = r_m31
        self.transform.m32 = r_m32
        self.transform.m33 = r_m33
        self.transform.m34 = 0.0
        
        self.transform.m41 = (startPoint.x + endPoint.x) / 2.0
        self.transform.m42 = (startPoint.y + endPoint.y) / 2.0
        self.transform.m43 = (startPoint.z + endPoint.z) / 2.0
        self.transform.m44 = 1.0
        return self
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't work, your code is heavier because you don't have to build a node and geometry every time, updating the geometry is enough.